# How to display checkbox values from an array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have an array of values from  a dropdown button (model) that generates dynamic checkboxes (destination). However, I wanted to display different criteria depending on the selected model and checked destination. Im sorry for this question. Im new to javascript and still learning. Thanks

Javascript:

```js
 function populate(model, destination) {
        var mod = document.getElementById(model);
        var des = document.getElementById(destination);
        des.innerHTML = "";
        if (mod.value == "model-a") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-A.1", "Model-A.2", "Model-A.3"];
 } else if (mod.value == "model-b") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-B.1", "Model-B.2", "Model-B.3"];
        } else if (mod.value == "model-c") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-C.1", "Model-C.2", "Model-C.3"];
    }

    for (var option in optionArray) {
        if (optionArray.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            var pair = optionArray[option];
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = pair;
            checkbox.value = pair;
            des.appendChild(checkbox);

            var label = document.createElement('label')
            label.htmlFor = pair;
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pair));

            des.appendChild(label);
            des.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the `id` by quotes:

```
    var mod = document.getElementById('model');
    var des = document.getElementById('destination');
```

```js
function populate(model, destination) {
        var mod = document.getElementById('model');
        var des = document.getElementById('destination');
        des.innerHTML = "";
        if (mod.value == "model-a") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-A.1", "Model-A.2", "Model-A.3"];
 } else if (mod.value == "model-b") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-B.1", "Model-B.2", "Model-B.3"];
        } else if (mod.value == "model-c") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-C.1", "Model-C.2", "Model-C.3"];
    }

    for (var option in optionArray) {
        if (optionArray.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            var pair = optionArray[option];
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = pair;
            checkbox.value = pair;
            des.appendChild(checkbox);

            var label = document.createElement('label')
            label.htmlFor = pair;
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pair));

            des.appendChild(label);
            des.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));    
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="model" onchange="populate();">
  <option></option>
  <option>model-a</option>
  <option>model-c</option>
  <option>model-b</option>
</select>
<hr>
<div id="destination"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, i have made few changes in your code.

```
    function populate(model, destination) {
            var mod = document.getElementById(model);
            var des = document.getElementById(destination);
            des.innerHTML = "";
            if (mod.value == "model-a") {
                var optionArray = ["Model-A.1", "Model-A.2", "Model-A.3"];
            } else if (mod.value == "model-b") {
                var optionArray = ["Model-B.1", "Model-B.2", "Model-B.3"];
            } else if (mod.value == "model-c") {
                var optionArray = ["Model-C.1", "Model-C.2", "Model-C.3"];
            }

            for (var option in optionArray) {
                if (optionArray.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
                    var pair = optionArray[option];
                    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
                    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                    checkbox.name = pair;
                    checkbox.value = pair;
                    checkbox.checked = true;
                    des.appendChild(checkbox);

                    var label = document.createElement('label')
                    label.htmlFor = pair;
                    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pair));

                    des.appendChild(label);
                    des.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                }
            }
        }

<select id="model" onchange="populate('model','destination');">
  <option></option>
  <option>model-a</option>
  <option>model-c</option>
  <option>model-b</option>
</select>
```